# Proguard / R8 rule to keep package-private class members

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-r8

For compiling an .aar library in an Android Java project I need to protect a static package-private method of a class to be protected from removal by R8:

```
public final class MyClass {
...
    static void myStaticMethod(...){
    ...
    }
...
}
```

I tried a Proguard / R8 Rule like this:

```
-keep class * {
    public protected *;
}
```

but it did not work, the method gets eleminated. Is there a special keyword for package-private methods?

Of course the workaround to mark the method with a `@Keep` annotation did work, but that leaves me with the task to find all package-private methods manually.

Comment: Which version of R8 are you using? You might have run into https://issuetracker.google.com/131462207, but that was fixed some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

In the end RTFM was the solution :) Reading the ["Class Specifications" section of the proguard manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage#classspecification) gave me the right idea:

```
-keep class * {
    !private *;
}
```

This keeps everything that has no private attribute which is a precise enough selection in my case.